# Why am I getting 404 with .htaccess in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

On my local machine I have .htaccess in the web route that reads:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But when I attempt to visit the following url - localhost/admin - I get "404 Not Found". I

I tried editing the last line to include a leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but that didn't work.

I made sure mod_rewrite was enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

My config settings were change in application/config/config.php to read:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I've checked my controller spelling and it appears to be correct (if I visit localhost/index.php/admin it loads the controller).

Comment: Now make sure `.htaccess` is even parsed. Put something random like `foobar` there in the top and check if you get error 500

Comment: If it _is_ being read/parsed, then add an R flag in addition to the L and see what it's being rewritten to.

Comment: @zerkms added foobar to .htaccess but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your last comment - you have your `.htaccess` turned off.

You can turn it on by specifying `AllowOverride All` in your apache configs

PS: try find current `AllowOverride` settings, most likely it is specified to `None` or something more restrictive than `All`